# Ctrl-o u in insert mode blocks for a few seconds

Tags: neovim

If I press `ctrl-o u` while in insert mode, vim (correctly) does an undo and then the status bar changes to something like `1 change; before #x  yy seconds ago` and stays so for about two seconds, unless some other key is pressed in the meantime. AFAIK this happens both in vim and nvim, in `vim -u NONE`, as well as with `set ttimeoutlen=0` and `set timeoutlen=0`. The same thing happens with `ctrl-o ctrl-r`, but AFAIK with no other `ctrl-o <command>` combination.

Why is that a problem? Well, I use a program that automates some things using RPC, and it so happens that calling `nrpc.request("nvim_get_mode")` blocks for the whole time vim is in this weird `ctrl-o u` state. It almost seems as if it were stuck waiting for some other possible key press.

Any idea why (neo)vim may be doing this, or how to disable it (or maybe just change the message timeout)? Incidentally, do you know of any other relevant timeout settings besides `timeoutlen` and `ttimeoutlen`?

EDIT: Minimal example:

`pipe-minimal.py`:

```python
import pynvim
from time import time, sleep

rpc: pynvim.Nvim = pynvim.attach("socket", path="my-socket")
last = time()
while True:
    now = time()
    print(rpc.request("nvim_get_mode"), now - last)
    last = now
    sleep(.1)
```

`minimal.vim`:

```
set timeoutlen=0
set ttimeoutlen=0
```

Run `nvim --listen my-socket -u minimal.vim` in one shell, `python pipe-minimal.py` in another. Then, type `ihi<Ctrl-o>u`. The terminal should freeze (or at least look frozen) with the cursor staying "blocky" and then unfreeze a few seconds later, with the cursor again "line-y". The output from the script should pause during the freeze, for me it looks like so:

```
…
{'mode': 'n', 'blocking': False} 0.104
{'mode': 'n', 'blocking': False} 0.104
{'mode': 'i', 'blocking': False} 0.104
{'mode': 'i', 'blocking': False} 0.104
{'mode': 'i', 'blocking': False} 0.103
{'mode': 'i', 'blocking': False} 0.103
{'mode': 'i', 'blocking': False} 0.103
{'mode': 'i', 'blocking': False} 0.103
{'mode': 'niI', 'blocking': False} 0.103
{'mode': 'niI', 'blocking': False} 0.103
{'mode': 'i', 'blocking': False} 0.103
{'mode': 'i', 'blocking': False} 3.065
{'mode': 'i', 'blocking': False} 0.101
{'mode': 'i', 'blocking': False} 0.101
{'mode': 'i', 'blocking': False} 0.101
{'mode': 'i', 'blocking': False} 0.101
…
```

Video: http://upload.uralyx.cz/tmp/vim-ctrl-o-u.mp4

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, with `vim -u NONE`,  `set ttimeoutlen=0`, `set timeoutlen=0`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! It might be helpful to include a minimal but complete example of an rpc process that demonstrates this behavior.